# Animating self.view.window.frame change

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm using animation with blocks and I'm trying to animate a change to my main window's frame.
Here is my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            self.view.window.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, self.view.window.frame.size.width, self.view.window.frame.size.height+20);
}];
```

However it doesn't animate like self.view.frame changing or something else. It's just plain crap without animation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is Wrong, Window is Fixed in FRAME And Bounds,
you cannot move Window, its top Root Container and has constant size, you should translate and transform your view only like this.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
            [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
            self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, -20.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+20);
}];
```

Comment: It doesn't work. What I want is to override the status bar. Only change to window frame works!